# conversion to type "none" double is not valid

Tags: sql, vb.net, datetime, format

```
Dim overdue As String

Dim penalty As String

If Not IsDBNull(dr.Item("overdue")) Then overdue = Format(dr.Item("overdue"), "yyyy-MMdd") Else overdue = "None"

If not IsDBNull(dr.Item("penalty")) Then penalty = Format(CDbl(dr.Item("penalty")), "#,##0.00") Else penalty = "None"
```

I'm changing my windows date to automatic calculate for penalty and overdue date

For example: Penalty = 10/day
Borrowed at May 01, 2021
Due date: May 02, 2021

If it exceeds for 3 days then the Overdue will be "May 05, 2021" and Penalty will count as "30"

Comment: If the value of `dr.Item("penalty")` is not a valid representation of a number then how do you expect `CDbl` to work? It seems like you expect some magic to occur based on that text. It won't. You need to work out what the logic is that you want to apply to it and then write code to implement that logic.

Comment: Assuming that `dr` is a `DataRow`, you can write that code much better: `Dim overdue = If(dr.IsNull("overdue"), "None", dr.Field(Of Date)("overdue").ToString("yyyy-MMdd"))`.